# YUI Rich Text Editor: Text coloring tools are not working

Tags: yui, richtextbox, color-picker

I'm using YUI RTE (version: 2.8.0r4). Only the text coloring tools are not working. It is enabled when I highlight the the text, but when clicking on the icon is not opening the color picker. Pls look at the snapshot,
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/599cd59d1b.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/599cd59d1b.png)

```
   var myEditor = new YAHOO.widget.Editor('body', {
                height: '300px',
                width: '99%',
                handleSubmit: true,
                dompath: true, //Turns on the bar at the bottom
                animate: true //Animates the opening, closing and moving of Editor windows

            });
myEditor.render();
```

Am I missing any js/css reference? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered here: http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=8741#p8741

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the following in this order:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.9.0/build/assets/skins/sam/skin.css"> 
<!-- Combo-handled YUI JS files: --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.9.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js&2.9.0/build/dragdrop/dragdrop-min.js&2.9.0/build/slider/slider-min.js&2.9.0/build/element/element-min.js&2.9.0/build/colorpicker/colorpicker-min.js&2.9.0/build/container/container_core-min.js&2.9.0/build/menu/menu-min.js&2.9.0/build/button/button-min.js&2.9.0/build/editor/editor-min.js"></script>
```

It will work for sure. Make sure no import is repeated otherwise it won't work.